# PHP: Show images from a folder

Tags: php, html, directory

I am just trying to display pictures from a folder in a browser. I have no web development experience. The below code is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Images from floder</h1>
<p>Using PHP</p>

<?php

   $files = glob("Notes/*.*");

   for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)

  {

  $image = $files[$i];

  print $image ."<br />";
  echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
   }

 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

This was the output of the html page when rendered on a browser:

```
Images from floder

Using PHP

"; echo 'Random image'."

"; } ?>
```

Comment: Same image is displaying all the time or what is your problem ?

Comment: please be more specific on what the problem is.. also, please do a `print_r($files)` to see if glob() gets something..

Comment: The index is off by one, it should start at 0.

Comment: what's the output of this line `print $image ."<br />";`

Comment: It's highly likely that the paths will not translate nicely to working URL's; check the web server configuration.

Comment: please do a var_dump or print_r on $files and post that here, we can't help you until you do that.

Comment: You have provided the name of the image but not the path to that image

Comment: I think you don't have PHP installed properly :)

Comment: @Jack You are right. I have absolutely no clue about using php and thought that browsers already have it.

Comment: I installed it using mac ports but I don't know how to proceed from here. Merely clicking the html doc is not producing the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**Update***

I think `php` code is not getting `parsed` make sure your test file extension is `php` not `html`

Make sure you have 'Notes/` directory with image files in same directory. And also add some validation / check extension etc.

You can use `scandir` and `pathinfo'`functions` to do this as below:

```
$dir = 'Notes/';
$files = scandir($dir);
$allowed_extensions = array('png', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowed_extensions)) {
        echo '<img src="' . $dir . $file . '" alt="Random image" />' . "<br /><br />";
    }
}
```